# i cant get back the scrolling effect

Tags: jquery, scroll, effect

hi i have done this and my links now works (b´cause they didn´t work) but the scrolling effect has gone, how do i get it back? thank you

this is my code from where my links did not work

```
<div class="container-fluid languages">
  <div class="container lang">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="navlangs">
        <li><a href="index_esp.html" target="_blank">ESPAÑOL</a></li>
        <li><a href="index_po.html" target="_blank">PORTUGUES</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">ENGLISH</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the script that i added the (if) line, but now the scrolling effect has dissapeard, can somebody help me? thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
   if (".navbar a" =! ".external"){}
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 900, function(){

      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have the if-statement there like that. There are several issues with your if-statement. First is `=!` which should be `!=`:

```
ORRIGINAL CODE:  if (".navbar a" =! ".external"){}

FIXED CODE:      if (".navbar a" != ".external"){}
```

The other issue is the condition in the statement. What are you comparing? `".navbar a"` is a string and is compared with another string, `".external"`. This condition is `false` all the time. What are you trying to do in the if-statement?

With these errors, the javascript will not run afterwards. That's why your code works perfect without it.

Comment: thanks for answering me, the thing is, in the first code i wrote the navigation to external pages, those three links were not working so i searched for a solution and i saw that someone has added this line  if (".navbar a" != ".external"){here goes the rest of li that have external links and now it works} to the jquery script so i put it there and then the links now are working but the scroll functioning to the anchor points now are disabled, if i click to a button in my navbar jumps instantly to its anchor point without scrolling smooth effect.

Comment: based on the code you provided here, I am pretty sure that the if-statement does not have to do anything with the anchors or anchor smooth scrolling. It causes the problem in the first place.

Comment: before i put that *if line* scroll effect worked right, once that line is there the effect does not work, i mean i fixed the link to external page problem and i have now this problem. can you tell me how can i put the scroll effect again?